# how to write route for multiple parameters in url in laravel?

Tags: php, url, laravel-5, routes

I want to pass two parameters in url. My url is http://localhost/buyforfund/fundraising/public/campaign_details/64

I want this url :
http://localhost/buyforfund/fundraising/public/campaign_details/64/campaign_product_details/26
on button click I want this url and I give the button link from route name. But an error occurs.

button link:

```
<a href="{{ route('campaign_product_details.detail',$result->id) }}" class="hvr-float-shadow">View</a>
```

Error:

> Missing required parameters for [Route: campaign_product_details.detail] [URI: campaign_details/{campaign_id}/campaign_product_details/{product_id}].

My route:

```
Route::get('campaign_details/{campaign_id}/campaign_product_details',function(){
        return view('/front/campaign_product_details');
    });
Route::get('campaign_details/{campaign_id}/campaign_product_details/{product_id}','front\CampaignDetailsController@showCampaignProductDetails')->name('campaign_product_details.detail');
```

Comment: Do you have issue in route or into your link tag?

Comment: i have issue in link tag @DarshanJain

Comment: See my answer as mentioned below. I hope you will get the idea about the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to pass two parameters like below:

```
Route::get('campaign_details/{campaign_id}/campaign_product_details/{product_id}', [
'as' => 'showCampaignProductDetails', 'uses' => 'CampaignDetailsController@showCampaignProductDetails']);
```

In your view:

```
route('showCampaignProductDetails',['campaingn_id'=>$campaign_id,'product_id'=>$productId]);
```

Comment: Glad to help you! @Bhoomipatel

Comment: how to pass multiple optional parameters in route?

Answer (score 0):

In your a tag second parameter is missing

```
<a href="{{ url('campaign_details/$result->id/campaign_product_details/$product_id }}" title="Edit signature">
```

You have define second parameter too.

Answer (score 0):

Also pass the product id

```
<a href="{{ route('campaign_product_details.detail',$result->id,$product->id) }}" class="hvr-float-shadow">View</a>
```