# I want to pass two parameters to the URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I want to pass two parameters with the route helper
One is the thread ID and the other is less so I want to pass both

**index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($works as $work)
<tr>
<td><a href="{{route('work.edit', ['id' => $work->id], ['project' => $param->id])}}">{{$work->input_person}}</a></td>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/work/edit/{id}/{project}', 'WorkController@edit')->name('work.edit');
```

Incidentally, the error appears like this

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: work.edit] [URI: work/edit/{id}/{project}].
```

I don't have a good idea of ​​what to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write route for multiple parameters in url in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527039/how-to-write-route-for-multiple-parameters-in-url-in-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it in the **same array**.

```
<a href="{{ route('work.edit', ['id' => $work->id,'project' => $param->id])}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
route('work.edit', ['id' => $work->id, 'project' => $param->id])
```